# Javascript refactoring spaghetti code of if/else

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, refactoring

Imagine a function which returns an object with 3 fields.

Now, I call the function for each element in an array and destructure these fields

```
 const array = [1, 2, 3];
 
 for (const element of array) {
    const {
      field1,
      field2,
      field3,
    } = await function(element);
    ...
 }
```

and I need to check that the values of those 3 fields are not contained in this array of tokens:

```
 const DANGEROUS_TOKENS = ["possible", "sure"];
```

if one of them is contained, I have to break the loop (to ignore the next iterations)

This is what I am doing:

```
for (const element of array) {
   const {
     field1,
     field2,
     field3,
     ...,
     fieldN
   } = await function(element);
        
   if (DANGEROUS_TOKENS.includes(field1)) {
      handleElement();
      break;
   } else if(DANGEROUS_TOKENS.includes(field2)) {
      handleElement();
      break;
   } ... the same for the next fields
}
```

How can I avoid this long if-else instruction?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need an array of properties to iterate over:

```
const props = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3'];
for (const element of array) {
  const result = await theFunction(element);
  if (props.some(prop => DANGEROUS_TOKENS.includes(result[prop]))) {
    handleElement();
  }
}
```